# Plesk 11.5 php-fpm.sock failed - resource temporarily unavailable & 502 Bad Gateway NGINX errors

Tags: nginx, plesk, php

This problem occurs on sites using Plesk 11.5 with NGINX and PHP-FPM processing enabled.

**php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable**

The websites will also display the following message: "502 Bad Gateway" NGINX

All connections to the website will fail because PHP-FPM will not allow any more connections to that particular website. The only solution I have been able to come up with is to restart PHP-FPM (service php-fpm restart). This works for a while until the PHP-FPM buffer fills up. I have tried changing the max connections in the domain specific php-fpm settings, but that does not seem to work.

Another interesting thing to note is that this particular domain is on a server with 30 other domains. Yet, when the error occurs, that domain is the only one having the issue. All other websites using PHP-FPM for PHP processing continue to work normally.

**PHP-FPM.CONF**

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
;log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
;daemonize = yes
```

**PHP-FPM Domain Config (from php-fpm.d folder)**

```
listen = php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = root
listen.group = psaserv
listen.mode = 0660

; Following options can be overridden
chdir = /
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 25
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

**NGINX.CONF**

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}
http {
    include   mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

        send_timeout 60;
        proxy_read_timeout 60;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  4;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;


    gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**Domain specific NGINX.conf**

(skipping a bunch of server/ssl/domain specific parameters. These two might be important).

```
client_max_body_size 128m;
proxy_read_timeout 10;
```

Comment: Please show PHP-FPM domain config.

Comment: Could you please provide php and php-fpm versions as well?

Comment: It's full error message "Resource temporarily unavailable" ? i've googled around and found that it looks like not full error string.

Answer (score 0):

Just to try localize the issue:

1. Switch pm = ondemand to pm = dynamic
2. increase pm.start_servers and pm.min_spare_servers to 4
3. add pm.max_requests = 500
4. add pm.status_path - read docs what is it and how it can be used.
5. restart php-fpm service

and observe for a while.

This changes can be overwritten by plesk, so be aware.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've tried a number of changes, and I try them regularly. There are some other posts on here with a similar topic, but not specific to Plesk. The piece that is VERY strange, is that this PHP-FPM hangup only seems to occur with a SINGLE domain on the server. The rest do not have the issue. Whenever I restart the php-fpm service, there are a number of running PHP-FPM processes, all by that domain user. It's like they are all stuck and not clearing. I have included all of my configs for reference.

Comment: Maybe 1. something special in PHP code/application used on this domain 2. load on domain is higher than on other domains. 3. custom "php settings"? 4. Custom "Web server settings"?